# how to retrieve hashed image using md5 from disk in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, hash, md5

Dears,
I've saved my image on the disk using Hash; I am already using `MD5 Hash` Function

```
Stream filestream = Upload1.PostedFile.InputStream;
BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(filestream);
byte[] bytee = br.ReadBytes((int)filestream.Length);
MD5 md5hashfun = MD5.Create();
byte[] data = md5hashfun.ComputeHash(bytee);
folder.Hash = BitConverter.ToString(data).Replace("-", "");

string filepath = Server.MapPath(Path.Combine(@"~/UploadedImages/" + folder.Hash));
Upload1.SaveAs(filepath);
```

I need to retrive and dislay those images; when i retrieve it normally using this code, image dosn't display.

```
        ImageButton imageButton = new ImageButton();
    string imgPath = "D:/Code/Image_Gallery/Image_Gallery/UploadedImages/" + file.Hash; //file.Hash is the hashed value
    imageButton.ImageUrl = imgPath;
    imgdiv.Controls.Add(imageButton);
```

Comment: you should store the hashed filename and than with that value you should create your imgPath variable.
your string value should be :
 string imgPath = filepath ;
instead of:
 string imgPath = "D:/Code/Image_Gallery/Image_Gallery/UploadedImages/" + file.Hash;

Comment: i store image on disk by using hashed value as name

Comment: but it is missing the folder.Hash directory than.
string imgPath = $"D:/Code/Image_Gallery/Image_Gallery/UploadedImages/{folder.Hash}/" + file.Hash;

Comment: i dont have problem in save,,

Comment: what is your filename when you save it? is it folder.Hash?

Comment: the first code store the image on disk using hashed value
on the path i give it.

Comment: No it's hash Value

Comment: example: D3B178B96BDAF84E4881E3AA7640C014

Comment: i just have aproblem when retrieve  data from disk, the image not display

Comment: try to test is hard coded such as: 
string imgPath = "D:/Code/Image_Gallery/Image_Gallery/UploadedImages/D3B178B96BDAF84E4881E3AA7640C014";

Comment: that dose not work

Comment: are you doing it in post back of page?

Comment: for explanation: i store the hashed value in database ans retrive from database to be able of retrive from disk

Comment: List<GSFile> files = FilesBAL.RetriveFolderItem(filePath);
                foreach (var file in files)
                { string imgPath = "D:/Code/Image_Gallery/Image_Gallery/UploadedImages/" + file.Hash; //file.Hash is the hashed value
    imageButton.ImageUrl = imgPath;
    imgdiv.Controls.Add(imageButton);}

Comment: setting variable should not be all unless it is posted back to UI

Comment: praty i can't understand your point,, can you explane please